# gssproxy: apache httpd as nfs-client? centos7

Tags: nfs, kerberos, gssapi

When Apache httpd attempts to access a user directory automounted with `sec=krb5p`, and presumably other `sec=krb` options, `gssproxy` issues a failure message and the web server replies with `403 Forbidden`. The debug option on gssproxy has not been sufficiently illuminating.

To rule out none `RPCGSS` issues, the `403` is not issued when a valid `KRB5CC` owned by uidNumber 48 (apache) is present in /tmp, and the web server will display the appropriate page. However, this is due to the behavior of `rpc.gssd`. `gssproxy` still issues the same failure message.

```
gssproxy: gp_rpc_execute: executing 6 (GSSX_ACQUIRE_CRED) for service "nfs-client", euid: 0, socket: (null)
gssproxy: gssproxy[639]: (OID: { 1 2 840 113554 1 2 2 }) Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, No credentials cache found

# cat /etc/gssproxy/gssproxy.conf 
[gssproxy]

[service/HTTP]
  mechs = krb5
  cred_store = keytab:/etc/gssproxy/http.keytab
  cred_store = ccache:/var/lib/gssproxy/clients/krb5cc_%U
  euid = 48

[service/nfs-server]
  mechs = krb5
  socket = /run/gssproxy.sock
  cred_store = keytab:/etc/krb5.keytab
  trusted = yes
  kernel_nfsd = yes
  euid = 0

[service/nfs-client]
  mechs = krb5
  cred_store = keytab:/etc/krb5.keytab
  cred_store = ccache:FILE:/var/lib/gssproxy/clients/krb5cc_%U
  cred_store = client_keytab:/var/lib/gssproxy/clients/%U.keytab
  cred_usage = initiate
  allow_any_uid = yes
  trusted = yes
  euid = 0

# klist -ke /var/lib/gssproxy/clients/$(id -u apache).keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/var/lib/gssproxy/clients/48.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2 apache/www.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   2 apache/www.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   2 apache/www.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia256-cts-cmac) 
   2 apache/www.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia128-cts-cmac)

# cat /etc/systemd/system/gssproxy.service.d/override.conf 
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/gssproxy -D --debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I used strace to see that gssproxy was looking for the keytab in /var/kerberos/krb5/user/48/client.keytab.  I also needed to set the selinux context:

```
chcon -t krb5_keytab_t /var/kerberos/krb5/user/48/client.keytab
ls -lZ /var/kerberos/krb5/user/48/client.keytab
-r--------. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:krb5_keytab_t:s0 /var/kerberos/krb5/user/48/client.keytab
```

It appears that the HTTP stanza is taking precedence over the nfs-client stanza for UID 48.